# How to prevent the appearance of error dialog when emf constraint is violated

Tags: eclipse-rcp, emf

I have declared an EMF AbstractModelConstraint that checks some criteria. My problem is when the validation fails, the runtime workbench shows an error dialog. How can I prevent its appearance?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the user can change this in Preference>Model Validation page. The validation message can be sent to the console view instead of popping up as a dialog.